# Delayed startup of network (Wi-Fi) icon

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet

When my Windows 7 Starter netbook boots up and after everything is loaded, it takes about 5 minutes before the network icon near the clock becomes functional. When there’s an available Wi-Fi signal – which automatically connects to my netbook as preconfigured – after the boot, my netbook seamlessly connects to it even if the network icon cannot be clicked or accessed; the icon is shown to be loading for about 5 minutes.

During this time, when I go to Network and Sharing Center, it takes the same time to load. So even while the icon and the Center cannot be accessed, I can surf the Internet. When my netbook was still new, it didn’t have this issue. How do I fix this?

Comment: I disabled FreemakeUtilsService in services.msc and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Check is the services configuration.

You can launch `services.msc` from the run windows in start menu or create console of this .msc to keep the display setup you prefer by launching `mmc.exe`, including services.msc in it and save the setup. Or use a third party software such as Nirsoft’s [ServiWin](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html)

The following services must be started in *automatic mode* (*not* delayed or manual):

- Netman
- Netprofm
- Eaphost
- WlanSvc
- DHCP (if needed)

If you have some useless services started or started in automatic instead of delayed or manual this may also slow down the services loading. This must be checked. To find some hints about services check (with caution) [Black Viper](http://www.blackviper.com/) for services configurations…

Please take note that other conditions may slow down the startup in general and the WiFi stuff in particular such as too many programs, drivers, etc at startup OR bad maintenance: fragmented HD, drivers with errors, etc…

Check this (*with caution*) with [MS TechNet Sysinternal’s Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the "ESET SHA Service". I've noticed that its status was "Starting" about for two minutes while blue circle hangs over network icon in notification area. After I've changed "Startup type" from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Delayed start)" the problem was solved.

Looks like sometimes some services or apps in startup tries to use same resources as Windows network connections services and hangs the normal process. In this case you should change startup type from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Delayed start)", "Manual" or even "Disabled" if you know you don't need it.

If you cannot open Services window through Control Panel, try <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> » `services.msc` »  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you cannot do that, try [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us/).

More, you can try some software like CCleaner to check Startup programs and disable them. 
Remember, that the list of Startup programs can be completely empty.